# ERROR: HRESULT: 0x8007007E System.IO.FileNotFoundException on Prolog and C# integration

Tags: c#, prolog, ffi, swi-prolog

I'm trying to call Prolog script file from C# program using SWI Prolog. I downloaded the code package from github (using this [link](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/contrib-swiplcs)). But, when I'm trying to run the HelloWorldDemo program the following error occurs:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)'
```

on Line 105 on the following code:

```
private static void LoadUnmanagedLibrary(string fileName)
    {
        if (_hLibrary == null)
        {
            _hLibrary = NativeMethods.LoadDll(fileName);
            if (_hLibrary.IsInvalid)
            {
                int hr = Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error();
                Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr); //here the error occurs
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried many solutions on the Internet, for example, provide the swi path on setenviromentvariable but the error still same.

Here is the code of HelloWorldDemo.cs:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("SWI_HOME_DIR", @"C:\Program Files\swipl\");  // I also used C:\Program Files\swipl\bin and didn't help too
            if (!PlEngine.IsInitialized)
            {
                String[] param = { "-q" };  // suppressing informational and banner messages
                PlEngine.Initialize(param);
                PlQuery.PlCall("assert(father(martin, inka))");
                PlQuery.PlCall("assert(father(uwe, gloria))");
                PlQuery.PlCall("assert(father(uwe, melanie))");
                PlQuery.PlCall("assert(father(uwe, ayala))");
                using (var q = new PlQuery("father(P, C), atomic_list_concat([P,' is_father_of ',C], L)"))
                {
                    foreach (PlQueryVariables v in q.SolutionVariables)
                        Console.WriteLine(v["L"].ToString());

                    Console.WriteLine("all children from uwe:");
                    q.Variables["P"].Unify("uwe");
                    foreach (PlQueryVariables v in q.SolutionVariables)
                        Console.WriteLine(v["C"].ToString());
                }
                PlEngine.PlCleanup();
                Console.WriteLine("finshed!");
            }
        }
```

So, how can I fix this issue?

Note: I'm using Win10 x64, visual studio 2017 community.

Comment: And what is the value of the variable _filename_ used in the failing method? To debug this issue I would start from here.

Comment: This method has been coded by SWI company itself, so I have no idea what it does, however, after debugging and tracking the code sequence I found that file name value is: "libswipl.dll". I think that he's trying to call this dll file but he couldn't find it in anywhere.

Comment: Do you install SWI-Prolog on your machine ?i think you don't config the project correctly.
It seems it could not find the native libraries of Prolog.

Comment: If the file has no path then it is expected that its location on your system is available through the environment variable PATH or (as explained above) through the environment variable SWI_HOME_DIR. I see your setting for the SWI_HOME_DIR but _PATH the bin directory of SWI-Prolog has to be added to the PATH environment variable_

Comment: I think that Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable method should make the process know where the installation folder is. In addition, I add SWI_HOME_DIR variable to Environment Variables on my machine, but also the problem is still exist :(